# Integration of exponentials of quadratic forms (general Gaussian itegrals) over semi-finite domains

Tags: quadratic-forms, integration

Hi

I'm interested in evaluating the integral of $e^{-s^T A s + b s}$ over a semi-infinite domain. $A$ is $\binom{N}{2}$x$\binom{N}{2}$ and has $N-1$ eigenvalues equal to $N$, and the rest 0. In particular, how does one deal with the limits of integration under an orthogonal transformation of the variables?

Deepak

Comment: Integral over what? (Please define your semi-infinite domain.) Also I have a hanging suspicion that your question will be better received at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: And as far as I know, $-a^TAs+bs$ is not a quadratic form...